# 'From' field in Laravel 4 Mail::send()

Tags: php, forms, email, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating some booking system and have HTML form in which user enter his email (and other stuff). I would like to get email as if user has send it from his email address, but my Gmail always shows that I have sent it (i.e. sender email address is same as 'username' from app/config/mail.php = XYZ@gmail.com).

This is Send::mail() method I am using

```
Mail::send('reservation-email', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
    $message->to('ABC@gmail.com', 'ABC')->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

This is my app/config/mail.php

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'XYZ@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'XYZ_password',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
);
```

I found out that I could use replyTo

```
Mail::send('reservation-email', ['data' => $data], function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
    $message->to('ABC@gmail.com', 'ABC')->subject($data['subject']);
    $message->replyTo($data['email'], $data['name']); // <--------------------
});
```

but then I do not know what is the purpose of 'from' field?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `from` is used when defining and address and name to new message.  `replyTo` is used when defining an address and name to the previous message.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confuse of the purpose of 'from' and 'replyTo'.

'from' will show to your users where they received email from (It can be set in your Mail::send method in each email or in your app/config/mail.php to apply to all emails).

'replyTo' will define which address that users would send their email to when they click 'reply' button.